# Hosting an Express/React app on Firebase: 404 on Express API calls

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

I am hosting a React app with an Express backend on Firebase Hosting.
While the local version works like a charm, making calls to my Express API yields 404.

The relevant parts of my file tree are as follows;

```
Project
 | - client // On deploy we use client/public as public folder
       | - public 
       |      | - index.html 
       | - src
       |      | - App.js // React app here
       |      | - Chat.js // Calls to API made here
       | - package.json
 | - firebase.json
 | - package.json
 | - server.js // Express API functions here
```

In my component `Chat.js` I make the following call:

```
    fetch("/api/input", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(this.state),
    })
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(
            res => { .... // get response from the API
```

To redirect this call from the React app hosted at http://localhost:3000, to the Express app that is locally hosted at :5000, my `client/package.json` includes

```
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000/",
```

And indeed, when **locally hosted, a POST request to "http://localhost:3000/api/input" yields the expected result.**

As for `server.js`, it includes the following:

```
const express = require('express');
...
var firebase = require("firebase");
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
...
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
...
app.post('/api/input', async (req, res, next) => { ... }) // Here's the relevant API call
...
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app) // export to firebase functions ('app')
```

Then, `firebase.json` is as follows:

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "client/build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      },
      {
        "source": "/api/**",
        "function": "app" //should make sure that calls to the API are getting to the Express app
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

When deploying the site using `firebase deploy`, the call to /api/input yields:
[image]

[image]

**Which steps may I have missed that prevents API calls from reaching my Express API?**

(Something I can imagine is that firebase deploy only deploys the built frontend, but not sure how to fix that)

Comment: app.post('/api/input') should be app.post('/input')

Comment: Tried it... changed nothing here. What does change that in that case, my locally hosted application then gives the error ``Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/input from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000/ (ECONNREFUSED)`` on``fetch``.

Comment: on your localhost you should request at localhost:5000/input , while on firebase you need to request guidedduckbot-fogccm.web.app/api/input

Comment: Okay, in case in React I  ``fetch("/input", {`` and in express I set ``app.post('/api/input')`` to ``app.post('/input') `` (everything else the same as above), that leaves me with the Proxy error on localhost and the same 404 on Firebase. So what other step would I then need to take?

Comment: I solved the proxy error on localhost (unrelated issue). Other than that, no progress on Firebase.

Comment: Could it have something to do with the folder structure, e.g. server.js existing in root but deploying client/public to firebase?

Comment: Make sure that your node version is `10+` because less than that it have depreciated on firebase.

Comment: your github link https://github.com/margotr/duckbot is 404

Comment: True, sorry having some trouble with Github. I removed the link for now.

Comment: @Teresa, where you able to solve this? I am having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You may forget configs for production. inside your server-side app.js

```
const path = require('path')
```

the `path` is inside of node core so you don't need to install it.

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'){
app.use(express.static('client/build'))

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'))
})
}
```

Comment: That does not seem to change anything about the situation....

Answer (score 0):

Firebase doesn't support nodejs+express apps.

It primarily hosts static content; in order to run [server code you will want to look into cloud functions.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started).